# Py2App application isn't reading changes made to text file

Tags: python, selenium, py2app

I have an application I've made using py2app, that is intended to read a text document and search each line therein in a search engine.

When I was testing this code in the terminal before using py2app, any changes made in the text file would be properly reflected the next time I ran the code. Example: I add a new line at the top of the document, it opens a new tab searching that string.

Now, after using py2app to bundle the code into a .app executable, it will only read the version of the file I gave it at creation, and won't read any changes.

I'm doing this on MacOS so here are the commands I've used to create the setup file and build it.

```
py2applet --make-setup searchscript3.py testdoc.txt
```

```
python3 setup.py py2app
```

I believe there's some way to implement a resources folder using "-r", but I cant get it to work, and even if so, how would I point the script to that directory?

Comment: Your software is pointing towards the `testdoc.txt` inside the archive, not the one found in the same folder as the app file. If you are using a path like `"testdoc.txt"`, you might want to switch to an explicit `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "testdoc.txt")` or `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "testdoc.txt")` depending on whether you want to point towards the doc inside the archive or next to it.

Comment: Okay, I changed that in the IDE and it's working in terminal. Do I need to change the make-setup to:

`py2applet --make-setup searchscript3.py os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "testdoc.txt")`

Comment: You change the path to your document in the software, not in the make-setup.

Comment: Do I still include testdoc.txt in the make-setup? Where should I put the text file in the dist/build files?

Comment: Well I don't know. You didn't say if you want your users (who will receive your dist folder) to use the program with their own testdoc.txt or yours.

Comment: I want them to be able to change the contents of testdoc to search different things as the need arises. Is it possible that including testdoc.txt in the DATA_FILES of setup.py might be part of the solution?